# Tab key jumping to hidden form

Tags: javascript, html, css, hidden, translate

The blocks are at a different distance, my script switches them via transform: translate. But when you go through the fields through the tab button, he switches them to the same incorrect. How to prevent it when you click on the tab to move to the hidden div?  display: none. Don't to offer. :)
`Example on jsfiddle:` https://jsfiddle.net/6c3xsj8q/5/

Comment: you dont want to move it to another another form on tab press?

Comment: @charankumar, yes. But i don't want to disable tab function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by javascript,

Disable tab press on submit button of first form

like this

```
$('#first button[type=submit]').keydown(function(objEvent) {
 if (objEvent.keyCode == 9) {  //tab pressed
    objEvent.preventDefault(); // stops its action
 }
})
```

Comment: Thx, It was too easy. I guess I'm too much working. =)